# MySQL Join tables with a condition

Tags: mysql

My SQL isn't up to this, but I'm pretty sure it is easy for an SQL guru - I'd rather figure out the right query rather than putting the logic into a PHP script...

So: I have 2 tables, one contains info about a club, a specific match and how many teams the club has entered for that match. The second table splits the entries into "divisions"

i.e.

```
mysql> describe Entries;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ClubId   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| MatchId  | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| NumTeams | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> describe Divisions;
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| MatchId  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ClubId   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Team     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Division | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Sample data:

```
Entries:
1, 1, 1 (Club1, Match1, 1 team)
1, 3, 2 (Club1, Match3, 2 teams)

Divisions:
1, 1, 1, 1 (Club1, Match1, Team1 is in division 1)
1, 1, 2, 2 (Club1, Match1, Team2 is in division 2)
1, 2, 1, 1 (Club1, Match2, Team1 is in division 1)
1, 2, 2, 2 (Club1, Match2, Team2 is in division 2)
1, 3, 1, 1 (Club1, Match3, Team1 is in division 1)
1, 3, 2, 2 (Club1, Match3, Team2 is in division 2)
```

Required result:

```
1, 1, 1 (Club 1, Match1, Team1)
1, 3, 1 (Club1, Match3, Team1)
1, 3, 2 (Club1, Match3, Team2)

- so not all the rows in Divisions are in the result.
  e.g, club1, match1, team2 isn't here because there
  is only one entry in match 1.
```

Now Entries.NumTeams can go up and down as a club enters or removes teams.  When a new team goes in, it gets put in division 1 (just so it is always in a division). When teams are removed, their entry in the Divisions table IS NOT removed (divisions are set manually, so if someone has decided Club X's 2nd team belongs in division 2, you want to keep that information even if Club X have not yet entered a 2nd team).

So, to print all teams in a division I need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Divisions WHERE Divisions.Team <= Entries.NumTeams
    (for the Entries row with the matching match and club)
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT Divisions.* from Entries LEFT JOIN Divisions ON 
    Divisions.MatchId = Entries.MatchId AND Divisions.ClubId = Entries.ClubId 
    WHERE Divisions.Team <= Entries.NumTeams
```

But I ended up with duplicate rows. I could probably get rid of them by using SELECT DISTINCT, but that makes me think my query is broken to start off with. I also swapped which table was left and right, but still got duplicates.

Will try the provided answers tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what you are doing here: `Divisions.Team <= Entries.NumTeams`. Is `Divisions.Team` the number of teams of a division? Also, could you provide more informations about what is a "match"? It doesn't sound like just the common concept of a match between 2 teams.

Comment: What is the datatype of Divisions.Team column?

Comment: can you provide your table structure with some data so we can test

Comment: All columns are INTs. Divisions table rows map the 1st 3 columns (MatchId, ClubId, Team) to a division. e.g. 1,2,3,4 means Team 3 in Club 2 in Match 1 belongs to Division 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DISTINCT` would remove duplicite rows, your query seems to be OK.

Comment: I agree, the query is fine, the likely reason for the dupes is @John3136's data is dirty.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I agree data is dirty - Divisions has some entries that don't correspond to Entries - but there is a good reason for me to leave them there, so it sounds like 'distinct' is the price I have to pay for dodgey data. Will confirm 100% tonight.

Answer (score 1):

use distinct  in mysql

```
SELECT distinct Divisions.* from Entries LEFT JOIN Divisions ON 
    Divisions.MatchId = Entries.MatchId AND Divisions.ClubId = Entries.ClubId 
    WHERE Divisions.Team <= Entries.NumTeams
```